# Two dimensional list population in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm struggling with this assignment using two dimensional lists and populating them with numbers. The assignment is:

> Create a table using a two dimensional list that stores a Fahrenheit
>   temperature and the equivalent Celsius temperature. Use the following
>   range of Fahrenheit temperatures: -10 through 100 in increments of 10.

I am stuck trying to populate the first column of my two-dimensional list with numbers -10 to 100. What I have so far:

```
ROWS = 11
COLS = 2


def main():
    list = [[0,0],
            [0,0],
            [0,0],
            [0,0],
            [0,0],
            [0,0],
            [0,0],
            [0,0],
            [0,0],
            [0,0],
            [0,0]]

    for i in range(ROWS):        
        for i in range(-10,110,10):
                list.insert(0, i)

    print(list)


main()
```

Comment: You certainly don't want to use the same variable `i` in both your loops.  That's not going to work very well.

Comment: Wait, why -10°F? I thought you were asked to do 10 to 100°F.

Comment: That was a typo. Starts at -10.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is a [list comprehension](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Comprehensions.html):

```
def inCelsius(temperature):
    return (temperature / 2) - 20

x = [[temperature, inCelsius(temperature)] for temperature in range(-10, 110, 10)]
```

This yields:

```
>>> x
[[-10, -25.0], [0, -20.0], [10, -15.0], [20, -10.0], [30, -5.0], [40, 0.0], [50, 5.0], [60, 10.0], [70, 15.0], [80, 20.0], [90, 25.0], [100, 30.0]]
```

Obviously your `inCelsius()` conversion would be different.

Note that you don't need to set up the list ahead of time; the list comprehension does that for you. Also note that Python's [list `insert()`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html) will insert the provided item at the position indicated. That means it will *increase* the size of your list - which you don't want unless you are growing your two dimensional list from scratch.

Finally, a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) would make your data structure more useful:

```
conversion = {temperature: inCelsius(temperature) for temperature in range(-10, 110, 10)}
```

This means that you can use `conversion` as a 'precomputed cache' to look up the value of a Farenheit temperature in Celsius:

```
>>> conversion[10]
-15.0
```

This means you're only computing the temperatures once per value. This is an optimization that can be handy if the conversion is complicated or processor intensive.

Comment: So list comprehension basically means you're able to add the for loop in the same line as where you defined the list? This is not something in our book, or something we went over class, but I'm sure the professor will accept it (hope so). Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes... though it's also seen as a more 'natural' way of expressing the idea of saying 'I want a list composed of `y` elements for each element in `y` range/list/set'.

Comment: Yes, your way seems much easier to remember and more logical. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

For a list of lists, it is best for you to assign things to specific indices by indexing the list itself. To be honest, I haven't used the .insert() method, ever. (I don't see the point of it, because otherwise you could just utilize list concatenation.)

Let's split this answer up to several parts:

**Solving the Problem**

First, learn how to index a list (also a list of lists). You probably either did not learn this yet, or you just forgot about using it. Here's an example:

```
>>> listA = ["Hello", "Hi", "Greetings"]
>>> listA[1]            # Returns the object at index 1 of the list, or the second object
"Hi"
>>> listB = [["1st object in list 1", "2nd object in list 1"], ["1st object in list 2", "2nd object in list 2"]]
>>> listB[0][1]         # Returns the object at index 1 of the object at index 0 of the larger list, which in this case would be:
"2nd object in list 1"
```

*How is this useful?* You can directly assign items to the list this way. For example:

```
>>> listC = [[1, 2],[3, 4]]
>>> listC
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> listC[1][1] = 100
>>> listC
[[1, 2], [3, 100]]
```

Use that to modify the pre-existing list that you created in the main function. You should probably use a for loop.

**Making Things Better**

(Disregard if you are in a hurry)

There are some ways that could help you later on when coding bigger and more complex projects, so that it might help you debug faster and more efficiently in the future.

- Using the variable `i` twice in the nested for loop isn't really a good idea. It can get you confused quite easily as you won't be sure which `i` are you referring to.
- Use more User-Defined Functions. Putting everything in main won't really help you, because it's basically the same as typing everything without the main() function. As of right now, I'm assuming that you will make more functions in the future, so if that's the case just disregard this.
- Defining a very long list that contains the same objects in each "slot" can be made easier using the **multiplication operator**. So, for example, you want to make a list that contains 10 objects, all of which are the integer `42`. Instead of typing that out, you could have just done `listA = [42] * 10`. This just saves a whole lot of time.
- Defining the list with the name `list` is a pretty bad idea. What if you want to use the `list()` function later on? You would be greeted by a terrible `TypeError: '[some type]' object is not callable`. So instead of using `list` as the name, change it to something like `temperatures` or something else that is more descriptive.

Comment: I guess someone found your answer not efficient.

And comparing to Nathaniel's answer I agree a bit (not my downvote though). You don't need to make the whole list and then assign each value one by one, using indexes. This would need too much code.

Nathaniel's solution, using list comprehensions is short, efficient and elegant.

Comment: @vmonteco You could utilize a for loop to assign each value. Not only it will be easier to read, it should be easier to understand. But that's my opinion though.